# Do WooCommerce Webhooks send X-WC-Webhook-Signature header on save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, http-headers, webhooks, request-headers

I'm trying to add a WooCommerce Webhook to hit an endpoint on my Ruby on Rails API. I can see in the logs that it is hitting the endpoint when I save the Webhook in the WP dashboard, but when I inspect said request I don't see the X-WC-Webhook-Signature header included with the other headers.

Does this header not get sent when it does the trial ping on save, and only when it is actually triggered by the Webhook's topic?

Comment: when the webook is saved, it uses [deliver_ping](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Webhook.html#613-642) and when the hook is called, it uses [deliver](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Webhook.html#278-323)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce does not send the X-WC-Webhook-Signature header when the webhook is saved (see links below, courtesy of Kaperto).

[deliver_ping](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Webhook.html#613-642) is called when a webhook is saved)

and

[deliver](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Webhook.html#278-323) is called when the webhook is actually triggered)